# Multiple option select form

Tags: php, html

I have created a HTML form where a user can enter his availability (which day of week). The form has a button to add new users so at the end I will have multiple DIVs for users, hence I have USER_DOW with two dimensions `USER_DOW[][]`.

```
<div id="user1" class="user" >
    <div class="name">
        <label>Name</label>                                         
        <input type="text" name="USER_Name[]">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Day of Week</label>                                          
    <select multiple id="USER_DOW" name="USER_DOW[][]" size='7'>
        <option value="Mon">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tue">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thu">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Fri">Friday</option>
        <option value="Sat">Saturday</option>
        <option value="Sun">Sunday</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm having issues accessing the elements in the PHP

```
foreach($USER_Name as $a => $b){
    echo $a+1;
    echo $USER_Name[$a]; 
    echo "Number of selected days for user " + count($USER_DOW); 
    foreach($USER_DOW as $c => $b){
            echo  $USER_DOW[$c][$a]; 
    } 
}
```

At the moment, if I add 2 users, one selecting Wed.& Sun. and the second only Mon., what I get is three days (count) for both users and on the first user all three are printed (Wed, Sun, Mon) while for the second nothing.

Any idea? Have I misunderstood the keys in the arrays?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` (or `var_dump($_GET)` depending of your form method) before `forreach` to better understand how the values are passed to script!

Comment: You are looping over _all_ entries in $USER_DOW multiple times, once  for every user. Acces the $USER_DOW array using the correct index, same as you are doing with $USER_Name[$a]: `foreach($USER_DOW[$a] …)`

Answer (score 1):

The names of input elements of a form are passed as written, without any interpretation.

So, in this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>

<?php if( count($_GET) ): ?>
<pre><?php var_dump($_GET); ?></pre>
<?php endif; ?>

/* FORM #1 */
<form action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="txt[0]" value="One">
    <input type="text" name="txt[1]" value="Two">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Test">
</form>

/* FORM #2 */
<form action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="txt[]" value="One">
    <input type="text" name="txt[]" value="Two">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Test">
</form>

/* FORM #3 */
<form action="test.php">
    <input type="text" name="txt[][]" value="One">
    <input type="text" name="txt[][]" value="Two">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Test">
</form>
<?php


?>
</body>
</html>
```

The generated URLs are:

```
/* FORM #1 */    test.php?txt[0]=One&txt[1]=Two&action=Test
/* FORM #2 */    test.php?txt[]=One&txt[]=Two&action=Test
/* FORM #3 */    test.php?txt[][]=One&txt[][]=Two&action=Test
```

(*rawurldecoded* for clarity)

When process `$_GET`/`$_POST` variables, PHP try to interpreter it, so in the first and second forms, the result is the same:

```
Array
(
    [txt] => Array
        (
            [0] => One
            [1] => Two
        )

    [action] => Test
)
```

But, in form #3, the result is:

```
Array
(
    [txt] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => One
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Two
                )

        )

    [action] => Test
)
```

because PHP increment first-level key, but not the deeper key.

If you expectation is to increment the deeper array, you have to specify first-level key in the form.
Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="txt[1][]" value="One">
<input type="text" name="txt[1][]" value="Two">
```

or, if code-generated, like:

```
<input type="text" name="txt[<?php echo $SomeVar; ?>][]" value="One">
<input type="text" name="txt[<?php echo $SomeVar; ?>][]" value="Two">
```

Comment: Thanks @fusion3k. Quite informative reply. After printing the `$USER_DOW` I got that it creates a single array (with three array entries). I think I should add the key as you suggested. As a matter of fact, I already have this outside the div as counter `<input type="hidden" value="1" id="numUsers" name="numUsers"/>` . How can I use this value in the key, i.e. for this part `<?php echo $SomeVar; ?>`

Comment: I am thinking something like `document.getElementById(numUsers).value` but I do not know if I can put javascript in the text

Comment: I don't know if I understand, but you can simply add (in the form)  the id of user in place of `$SomeVar`. Something like `<div id="user1">(...)<input name="txt[1][]" (...) <div id="user2">(...)<input name="txt[2][]"`.

Comment: I fixed it. I used the js to change the element name accordingly when I create it, as I do not have a form for each 'user'. I have a single form for all users (e.g. a team).

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. But the id `id="user1"` is not unique for each user? In the regard, please also note that id **must be unique** in a html page (i.e. `id="USER_DOW"`)

Comment: I have used the class to get the proper element even though I have used the same ID like this `var dow = document.getElementsByClassName("USER_DOW")[num-1];` where `num` is the user number and -1 because of the zero-start of the arrays. Then `dow.setAttribute("name",'USER_DOW[' + num + '][]');` to change the name accrodingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

function do_form($index) {
?>
<div id="user<?= $index ?>" class="user" >
    <div class="name">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="USER_Name[<?= $index ?>]">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Day of Week</label>
    <select multiple id="USER_DOW" name="USER_DOW[<?= $index ?>][]" size='7'>
        <option value="Mon">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tue">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="Wed">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thu">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Fri">Friday</option>
        <option value="Sat">Saturday</option>
        <option value="Sun">Sunday</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
} 
?>

<form method="POST">
    <?php do_form(1); do_form(2); ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Sample output after submit:

```
array (size=2)
  'USER_Name' => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => string 'foo' (length=3)
      2 => string 'bar' (length=3)
  'USER_DOW' => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Mon' (length=3)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'Mon' (length=3)
          1 => string 'Tue' (length=3)
```